# Independent Random Variables: X=Y almost surely

Tags: measure-theory, independence

I have just come out of my midterm exam on my measure theory course, and I had some trouble solving the following question:

"Let $X,Y$ be a pair of independent random variables. Suppose that $X=Y$ almost surely. Show the following:

1. $P(X\leq r) \in \{0,1\}$ for any $r\in \mathbb{R}$.
2. $P(X\in A) \in \{0,1\}\ \  \forall A\in B_\mathbb{R}$."

I know that the almost surely condition implies that $P(X\neq Y)=0$, hence, both variable will have the same distribution or law $\mu_x=\mu_y=\mu$. What would be the next steps?

Thanks for the responses, I would really like to know to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent,
$$ \mathbb{P}(X\in A,Y\in A)=\mathbb{P}(X\in A)\mathbb{P}(Y\in A)$$
for any Borel set $A$. But $\mathbb{P}(X\in A,Y\in A)=\mathbb{P}(X\in A)=\mathbb{P}(Y\in A)$ since $X=Y$ a.s., hence
$$\mathbb{P}(X\in A)=\mathbb{P}(X\in A)^2 $$
and $\mathbb{P}(X\in A)\in\{0,1\}$.

Comment: Thanks, just one question. I get the RHS of the last equation (as X and Y has the same distribution); but I do not quite understand how $P(X \in A, Y \in A) = P(X \in A) = P(Y \in A)$ follows from X=Y a.s.

Comment: Note that $\{X\in A,Y\in A\}\subset \{X\in A\}$, and $\{X\in A\}\setminus \{X\in A,Y\in A\}$ is contained in $\{X\neq Y\}$, which has probability zero.

Comment: Great, thanks. What I did not understand even in the exam was why they ask parts (i) and (ii) separately, as showing it for (ii) also implies (i).

Comment: I thought that was a bit strange too. Perhaps part (i) was supposed to be a "warmup" of sorts.